# afterSubmit function is not trigger when the order is placed through webservice API

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitetalk

I have my suitescript to run when a new sales order is created.  It's working fine when I login to netsuite and manually create a sales order.  I know my script is working when I received a test email from my suitescript code.

However, when the order is placed through a webservice API, my suitescript is not trigger, I dont' receive the test email.

My question, does suitscript suppose to work when the order is placed through webservice API as well or it has to create a suitetalk way to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

User event scripts are triggered by WebServices API as well. Check if your script is applied to the role and user the Webservice integration is linked to.

More info:
[Deploying a Script by using the Deployments Sublist](https://ursuscode.com/public/netsuitehelp/section_4490584904.html)

Answer (score 3):

Also check if you have the option "RUN SERVER SUITESCRIPT AND TRIGGER WORKFLOWS" checked under webservices preferences.  You can reach this page by going to Setup > Integration > Web Service Preferences

Comment: Yes I did check that settings and it's checked.  thanks @Rusty Shackles